# Как остановить процесс в shell скрипте?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, процесс, grep

Мне нужно написать shell-скрипт. Его суть сводится к цикличной загрузке модуля драйвера, запуска тестового приложения, если приложение не упало в течении трех секунд, остановки его и последующей выгрузки драйвера. 
Пока что написал следующее:

```
#!/bin/sh
for((i=0; i<200; i++))
do
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.111.1/extra/ump.ko
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.111.1/extra/mali.ko
cd /opt/mali/cube
./cube &> log &
sleep 3
kill pid
rmmod mali
rmmod ump
done
```

Как я понимаю, нужно воспользоваться командой kill, но как передать ей id процесса? Ну, т.е. нужно "грепнуть" jobs -l по имени процесса, но grep ведь вернет строчку, а не число.

Comment: *grep ведь вернет строчку, а не число* вот эту строку и передавай в kill. У тебя в скрипте все абы числа - они строки (да и весь скрипт - сплошь текст), и ничего...

Comment: под "строчкой, а не числом", я имел ввиду не различие в концепциях string и int, а в том, что в этой строке будет еще много разного мусора: [3]+  233 Stopped                ./cube 1>&log из которого мне нужно только число 233.

Comment: А еще есть команда `killall` которая в качестве параметра принимает как раз имя процесса. `killall cube` должен помочь

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

Comment: @Mike, Боже, почитайте документацию что ли. *$!* после запуска будет содержать PID. И никогда не используйте *killall* в скриптах.

Comment: пробовали: `timeout 3s cube &>log` (что остановит cube после 3 секунд, но может раньше вернуться, если cube раньше завершится)

Comment: нет, не знал о такой команде, и это именно то, что нужно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как писал выше в комментариях 0andriy, после запуска процесса, его PID можно скопировать в переменную из $!.